# Using xseticon to set vim icon

Tags: vim

I've been trying to set the icon of vim terminals that I run by writing a small line in my .vimrc:

```
execute '!xseticon -id \"' . v:windowid . '\" /usr/share/icons/Faenza/apps/16/vim.png'
```

However, I can't get it to properly work. The strings are concatenating and all, however I get the error:

```
xseticon: error: Invalid window id format: "0".
```

which I think is because it is running the script before vim can properly grab window ids, perhaps because it is not yet running.

How can I work around or solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, when `.vimrc` is executed, the window hasn't yet been created. You can use the `VimEnter` event for that:

```
:autocmd VimEnter * execute ...
```

Comment: Perfect! I didn't have to escape my " characters in the working line.

Now I just have to make it reset the icon on close ... but I think you got me on the right track and I can figure that out now.

Comment: Great; glad I could help. For closing, there's the `VimLeave` event.